# Looking for Regex pattern for maximum matches

Tags: regex, passwords

I'm looking for a regex pattern that can limits matches based on maximum occurrences.

For example, match an alphanumeric string between **6-12 characters in length**, and contains **minimum 2**, but **NOT MORE THAN 4**, uppercase letters, regardless of each of their positions in the string.

I've tried this pattern, but it only matches if the uppercase letters are located next to each other.

```
^([A-Z]{2,4}).{8,12}$
```

Valid matches would be:

```
HamBurger (2 uppercase, Length = 9)
LeTtUce (3 uppercase, Length = 7)
TACOss (4 uppercase, Length = 6)
```

But invalid matches would be:

```
ABCDE1234 (too many uppercase letters)
aBcDeFgHiJ (too many uppercase letters)
ADBC (length too short)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You should give [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) a good read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a lookahead based solution like

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$).{6,12}$
```

Or, to make it more streamlined, move the length check to the start (into the lookahead):

```
^(?=.{6,12}$)(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XaMK6t/1/) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/XaMK6t/2)) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5B%5EA-Z%5D*%5BA-Z%5D)%7B2%2C4%7D%5B%5EA-Z%5D*%24).%7B6%2C12%7D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires two to four repetitions of 0+ chars other than uppercase letters followed with an uppercase letter and then any 0+ chars other than uppercase letters to the end of the string
- `.{6,12}` - 6 to 12 chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! This is just what I needed.